# Consultation with GROUP BY in a Eloquent ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sqlyog

I have this query:

`SELECT * FROM contactcompany WHERE recipientid = 27 GROUP BY userid`

but I don't know how to add it in an eloquent form.

Comment: Without seeing actual code, we can't answer without guessing. What are the relevant models? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: $messages = Contactoempresa::where('recipientid', $user->id)
             ->where('statusconem', 'A')
             ->with('users')
             ->Groupby('idusuario')
             ->get();

Comment: can be grouped in javascript with this function 
        const filteredMess = [];
                    data.forEach(meessag => {
                    if (!filteredMess.find(cat => cat.idusuario == meessag.idusuario)) {
                       const { id, idusuario, idempresa, nombreconem, motivoconem, created_at, users } = meessag;
                       filteredMess.push({ id, idusuario, idempresa, nombreconem, motivoconem, created_at, users });
                    }
                  });

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
DB::table('contactcompany')
         ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, userid'))
         ->where('recipientid', 27)
         ->groupBy('userid')
         ->get();
```